# Python dir(dict) vs dir(dict.__class__)

Tags: python

What is the difference between `dir(x)` and `dir(x.__class__)`? The latter returns a different list of attributes, but that overlaps with the former.

For example, SQLAlchemy's `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` function creates a new `Engine` instance. When I call `dir(engine)` (assuming `engine` is the var pointing to the appropriate instance) I get the following list returned:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_connection_cls', '_echo',
'_execute_clauseelement', '_execute_compiled', '_execute_default',
'_execution_options', '_has_events', '_run_visitor', '_should_log_debug',
'_should_log_info', 'connect', 'contextual_connect', 'create', 'dialect',
'dispatch', 'dispose', 'driver', 'drop', 'echo', 'engine', 'execute', 'func',
'has_table', 'logger', 'logging_name', 'name', 'pool', 'raw_connection',
'reflecttable', 'run_callable', 'scalar', 'table_names', 'text', 'transaction',
'update_execution_options', 'url']
```

Calling `dir(engine.__class__)` results in the following:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_connection_cls',
'_execute_clauseelement', '_execute_compiled', '_execute_default',
'_execution_options', '_has_events', '_run_visitor', '_should_log_debug',
'_should_log_info', 'connect', 'contextual_connect', 'create', 'dispatch',
'dispose', 'driver', 'drop', 'echo', 'execute', 'func', 'has_table',
'logging_name', 'name', 'raw_connection', 'reflecttable', 'run_callable',
'scalar', 'table_names', 'text', 'transaction', 'update_execution_options']
```

There's overlap between these two results, but also differences and I haven't found anything especially useful in the documentation that explains the difference and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roughly, `dir(instance)` lists the instance attributes, the class attributes and the attributes of all base classes.  `dir(instance.__class__)` only lists the class attributes, the attributes of all base classes.

An important thing to keep in mind when using `dir()` is this note from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir):

> Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

Answer (score 2):

The difference should be self-evident: in one case you are asking for the `dir()` of an instance, and in the other case you are asking for the `dir()` of the class that served as its template. Instances may have attributes that are not on the class by creating them in the `__init__()` method.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer = 42

f = Foo()
set(dir(f)) - set(dir(Foo))
>>> set(['answer'])
```

Instance attributes are used to store data specific to some instance. Class attributes store data shared by all instances of the class or, sometimes, used by the class itself. Methods are a special case because they are actually stored both places (they are defined on the class, but bound to each instance later).

Comment: "[Methods are] bound to the instance when it is created".  I don't think so -- bound methods are created upon attribute access, not when the instance is created.  (Once again, I think your answer is much easier to read than mine.)

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting detail!