# Why attribute in __init__() method not show in dir(Foo) API?

Tags: python

I am not able to understand why dir(Foo) doesn't show attribute defined in **init** method.i searched and found Kindall answer.But still not able to comprehend completely.
[Python dir(dict) vs dir(dict.__class__)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693158/python-dirdict-vs-dirdict-class)

```
class Foo(object):
    kind = 'car'
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def bar(self, b):
        return self.a + b

f = Foo(1)
print(dir(Foo))  #['bar','kind']
print(dir(f))    #['a','bar','kind']
```

Comment: `Foo` has no `a` attribute. Try `Foo.a` if you want to check.

Comment: @user2357112,thanks for your quick reply,you are right that, Foo has no *a* attribute. But, why? and also why *f* has that attribute.

Comment: @d.m because `a` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `a` is defined only **after** `__init__` is called. This is an object variable, specific to each `Foo` **object**. `kind` on the other hand, is defined in the class namespace, it is a **class** field. That is why when you `dir(Foo)`, you do not see `a` - it only lists stuff belonging to the class. `f` on the other hand, is an object that has already called `__init__`, and thus has its `a` defined.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, `a` gets created when `__init__` is called. Since `dir(Foo)` doesn't call `__init__`, `a` never gets created.

Put another way, `a` is part of an *instance* of `Foo`, not of `Foo` itself. There is no such thing as `Foo.a`, only `Foo().a`.

In Python, it is possible to add attributes to a user-defined object at any time. Perhaps the following will make things clearer:

```
class Bar(object):
    pass

bar = Bar()
print(dir(bar))
bar.a = 42
print(dir(bar))
```

The main way in which your example is different is that `a` happens to get created during the `__init__` call, not after it.